# How can I create a Jenkins Docker image that uses provided ssh keys for jenkins user?

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh

While I create an image based on official Jenkins Docker and copy `.ssh` directory to `jenkins` user's home (`/var/jenkins_home`), owner of the `/var/jenkins_home/.ssh` becomes `root` which prevents me to open ssh session with `jenkins` user. Using `RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /var/jenkins_home/.ssh` in `Dockerfile` does not work.

Also, permissions of the files copied while creating image becomes `644` by default. However, to be able to open ssh session, permissions of `/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa` must be `600`.

How can I create an image from official Jenkins Docker image having provided ssh keys for `jenkins` user?

Answer (score 10):

Official Jenkins Docker image defines Jenkins home directory(`/var/jenkins_home`) as `VOLUME` which prevents `RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /var/jenkins_home/...`to be effective:

```
$ touch test.txt

$ vi Dockerfile
--- Dockerfile ---
FROM jenkins:2.32.3

COPY test.txt /tmp
COPY test.txt /var/jenkins_home/test.txt

USER root

RUN chown 1000:1000 /tmp/test.txt
RUN chown 1000:1000 /var/jenkins_home/test.txt

USER jenkins
--- Dockerfile ---

$ docker build -t myjenkins .
...

$ docker run -it myjenkins /bin/bash
jenkins@750f43b7e9ec:/$ ls -all /var/jenkins_home/test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 24 06:54 /var/jenkins_home/test.txt
jenkins@750f43b7e9ec:/$ ls -all /tmp/test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 0 Mar 24 06:54 /tmp/test.txt
```

Official Jenkins Docker has a solution for it: Copying directories and files those must be under jenkins user's home to `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/`. When jenkins container starts, it will check `/var/jenkins_home` has this reference content, and copy them there if required. (See `Installing more tools` of [official Jenkins Docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/)).

```
$ touch test.txt

$ vi Dockerfile
--- Dockerfile ---
FROM jenkins:2.32.3

COPY test.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/test.txt
--- Dockerfile ---

$ docker build -t myjenkins .
...

$ docker run -it myjenkins /bin/bash
jenkins@1e9520a92f8e:/$ ls -all /var/jenkins_home/test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 0 Mar 24 08:21 /var/jenkins_home/test.txt
```

Now we need to set file's permission to `600`:

```
$ touch test.txt

$ vi Dockerfile
--- Dockerfile ---
FROM jenkins:2.32.3

COPY test.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/test.txt

USER root

RUN chmod 600 /usr/share/jenkins/ref/test.txt

USER jenkins
--- Dockerfile ---

$ docker build -t myjenkins .
...

$ docker run -it myjenkins /bin/bash
cp: cannot open ‘/usr/share/jenkins/ref/test.txt’ for reading: Permission denied
```

Strange! The error is thrown by Jenkins' initialization script: [jenkins.sh](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/jenkins.sh). The script runs while Jenkins container is starting. What we can do here is changing file permission while container starts instead of changing it in `Dockerfile`. Then we need an entrypoint script that copies the file to `/var/jenkins_home`, changes it's permission and, as a last step, calls `jenkins.sh`. I created `entrypoint.sh` based on https://github.com/openfrontier/docker-jenkins/blob/master/entrypoint.sh.

```
$ touch test.txt

$ vi entrypoint.sh
--- enrypoint.sh ---
#! /bin/bash -e

cp /usr/share/jenkins/ref/test.txt /var/jenkins_home
chmod 600 /var/jenkins_home/test.txt

echo "start JENKINS"
# if 'docker run' first argument start with '--' the user is passing jenkins launcher arguments
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]] || [[ "$1" == "--"* ]]; then
    exec /bin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh "$@"
fi
exec "$@"
--- enrypoint.sh ---

$ vi Dockerfile
--- Dockerfile ---
FROM jenkins:2.32.3

COPY test.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/test.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

USER root

RUN chown 1000:1000 /entrypoint.sh \
  && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

USER jenkins

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
--- Dockerfile ---


$ docker build -t myjenkins .
...

$ docker run -it myjenkins /bin/bash
start JENKINS
jenkins@770ba9099cb4:/$ ls -all /var/jenkins_home/test.txt
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 0 Mar 24 10:36 /var/jenkins_home/test.txt
```

Let's make it for `ssh` directory having `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files. Note that as directory name I used `ssh` instead of `.ssh`. Otherwise content of `.ssh` would directly be copied to `/var/jenkins_home`. That is how Docker behaves for directories whose names begin with a dot (e.g. .m2).

Here is all the necessary steps. You can see that I could successfully open an ssh session from within container:

```
$ ls -all
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser mygroup  54 Mar 24 13:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 myuser mygroup  70 Mar 24 09:54 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 242 Mar 24 13:35 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 338 Mar 24 13:33 entrypoint.sh
drwx------ 2 myuser mygroup  36 Mar 24 11:24 ssh

$ ls -all ssh/
total 8
drwx------ 2 myuser mygroup   36 Mar 24 11:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser mygroup   54 Mar 24 13:41 ..
-rw------- 1 myuser mygroup 1679 Mar 24 11:23 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup  391 Mar 24 11:23 id_rsa.pub

$ vi entrypoint.sh
--- enrypoint.sh ---
#! /bin/bash -e

mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home/.ssh
mv /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/id_rsa /var/jenkins_home/.ssh
chmod 600 /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa

echo "start JENKINS"
# if 'docker run' first argument start with '--' the user is passing jenkins launcher arguments
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]] || [[ "$1" == "--"* ]]; then
    exec /bin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh "$@"
fi
exec "$@"
--- enrypoint.sh ---

$ vi Dockerfile
--- Dockerfile ---
FROM jenkins:2.32.3

# Copy ssh as .ssh
COPY ssh/ /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

USER root

# Change owner of .ssh directory and files under it to
# jenkins user's owner (1000:1000) and make sure
# permisson of id_rsa is not 600.
RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh \
    && chmod 644 /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN chown 1000:1000 /entrypoint.sh \
    && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

USER jenkins

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
--- Dockerfile ---


$ docker build -t myjenkins .
...

$ docker run -it myjenkins /bin/bash
jenkins@3090dda362d6:/$ ls -all /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 1679 Mar 24 08:23 /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa

jenkins@3090dda362d6:/$ ssh rose1
The authenticity of host 'rose1 (XX.XX.XX.XX)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'rose1,XX.XX.XX.XX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Thu Mar 23 15:55:41 2017 from 10.74.200.56
[jenkins@rose1 ~]$
```

**Update 1**

I have uploaded given files to GitHub:  https://github.com/kumlali/stackoverflow_answers/tree/master/docker_jenkins_ssh_keys/answer1

Comment: why do you use /bin/tini? there is a warning while executing

Comment: ```
Please update your scripts to use /sbin/tini or simply tini going forward.
Previous path has been preserved for backwards compatibility,
but WILL BE REMOVED in the future. (around Jenkins >= 2.107.2+)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a little bit complex but more generic way to achieve that. New solution requires;

- [`ssh-agent`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/x/WQLiAw), [`credentials`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/x/xxOMAw) and [`ssh-credentials`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/x/dxSMAw) plugins
- Plugin installation while creating Docker image ([Installing more tools - Preinstalling plugins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#preinstalling-plugins))
- Configuring Jenkins upon startup by executing [post-initialization script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/x/aQBGAg).

Main idea here is to copy ssh keys into a directory other than `JENKINS_HOME`, adding them to Jenkins' credentials by using post-initialization script and using `ssh-agent` plug-in for ssh.

I have uploaded necessary setup and instructions to GitHub: https://github.com/kumlali/stackoverflow_answers/tree/master/docker_jenkins_ssh_keys/answer2